# Probability card turning over question

Tags: probability

> Let $n ∈ N$. Two packs of cards each containing cards numbered $1$ to
>   $n$ are shuffled and placed on the table. One by one, two cards are
>   simultaneously turned over from the top of the packs. What is the
>   probability that at some point the two revealed cards have the same
>   number?

Heres my thinking: Let the sample space be $(i,j)$ where $i$ and $j$ go from $1$ to $n$. Let event $A$ be where $i$=$j$ so $|A| = n$ because theres $n$ of $(1,1) (2,2) , ...(n,n)$. The size of the sample space is $n^2$ because we can pick i from 1-n and j from 1-n. So the probability must be $\frac{1}{n}$ But the answer is something completely different. Can anyone tell me whats the right path to this question and why, I never know where to start and what technique to use with probability questions.

Comment: Would it make any difference to the question if you did not shuffle one of the packs?

Comment: No but I think they just mean by shuffled that the pack isnt ordered

Comment: The answer can be found by subtracting the probability that the sequence in the second deck is a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the first deck from $1$.  A derangement is a permutation with no fixed points.

Comment: This, and the secretary problem, and the couples in a row problem, and many others, have an answer close to $e^{-1}$ or $1-e^{-1}$ for large $n$

Comment: Can someone tell me why my method is wrong though, also how do i know which method I should use to approach a question

Comment: Your method is wrong by not taking into account the possibility that a match card has already been chosen.  Fr example, the first pick gives you the pair (j,k).  Then when later k comes up in the first deck or j comes up in the second deck, no match is possible.